# PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called, existing state of has been invalidated

Tags: database, oracle, session, plsql

Lets say I have 2 packages Test_1 and Test_2, each of these packages have procedures A and B, Test_1.A runs in indefinite loop and it calls Test_2.B.

When I make changes in Test_2.B and recompile the package I get the below error.

```
ORA-04061: existing state of package body 
"Test_2.B" has been invalidated
ORA-04065: not executed, altered or dropped package body "Test_2.B"
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "Test_2.B"
ORA-04061: existing state of  has been invalidated
ORA-04061: existing state of package body "Test_2.B" has been invalidated
ORA-04065: not. At LocationORA-06512: at line 1
ORA-06512: at "Test_1.A", line 10
```

If I cancel the loop for Test_1.A and rerun, it works but I do not want to do that.

I have tried using below, but they do not work.

```
   DBMS_SESSION.MODIFY_PACKAGE_STATE(DBMS_SESSION.FREE_ALL_RESOURCES);
   DBMS_SESSION.RESET_PACKAGE;
```

Comment: Can you move all the variables from the package specification to the package body?  A lot of PL/SQL packages declare everything as public variables for no reason and create session-persistent data even though it's not intended.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it's such a strange issue of `oracle database` and works(being resolved) in a second call as you have mentioned.

You may use two manners to suppress :

- Use `pragma serially_reusable`:

  > create or replace package Test_2 as
  >
  > `pragma serially_reusable`;
  >    v_abc_1 number;
  >    v_def_2 date;
  >    ...
  >
  > begin
- If you are on a *RAC database*, your dba may issue this command ( if suitable for your system ), or just alter for your session by yourself :

  > `alter system set "_disable_fast_validate"=true scope=both;`
  >
  > `alter session set "_disable_fast_validate"=true`

  as an *alternative*.

Comment: This looks like a system variable, will it impact any other day to day operations ?

Comment: @vakul sure, it should be tested by your dba. By the way, I didn't try whether applicable only for a session.

Comment: @vakul i've tried and edited my answer, you may also use `alter session` option provided your db is `RAC`.

Comment: Thanks, looks like we are not on RAC server, its not working.

Comment: @vakul did you try the first part( using `pragma serially_reusable` ) ?

Comment: We have almost 500 packages which get called from main package, looking for any workaround instead of changing all the 500 packages.

Answer (score 0):

The clue is "ORA-04061: existing state of package body "Test_2.B" has been invalidated". That means that package Test_2.B has a state (usually variable declared in the scope or body). Each compilation resets the values of such variables, and Oracle assumes that this is a problem for you.